# Chrome (Android) -- Casting authenticated HTML5 videos

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

Chrome (for Android) now overlays a Cast button on all HTML5 video content that it finds. The problem is that the content on our site requires authentication to view. Tapping the Cast button shows this toast:

"Unable to cast video due to site restrictions"

Is there a way to...

a) Provide the cast button with the necessary authentication params

and if not (a), then:

b) Provide a meta tag telling Chrome not to put a Cast button on our videos

We plan to provide Chromecast functionality in our Android app, but it's not done yet.

Comment: Why does android have this problem and not chrome desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to your CDN. look at this: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player check out the CORS Reference.

Works for me.